# Can I push notifications to Android without ANDROID_ID?

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to push notifications to my Android app, but I don't want to use ANDROID_ID to create PUSH_TOKEN, so I created a unique ID myself to get PUSH_TOKEN from Google.

My question is: can GCM push notifications to my Android device with my unique ID?

Comment: I don't think so coz your registration id is got using the `SENDER_ID` which you get from the console  `regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);`

Answer (score 0):

No, you must have a GCM registration id from the app installation you want to send a message to.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Answer (score 0):

No.. you should have the Sender Id that will be got from Google API Console when you registering on it. Try to use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) tutorial . This will help you.